# How to scale PDF image to browser size?

Tags: html, css, pdf, resize

I am inserting a PDF of a staff tree into a html file. The only object on the whole page will be this PDF.

I am struggling to figure out how to get the PDF to fill 100% height of the browser window.

this is what I have got so far:

HTML:

```
    <div class="tree">
<embed src="images/staffbook/organisationalstructure.pdf"  width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  body {
    width:100%;
    height:1005;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
}

.tree {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SLjb/)

The code seems to be somewhat ok but the image itself in the PDF doesn't fit very well.

is there something better I can use to keep the quality but isn't a jpeg, png, gif etc..?

Comment: Does adding 100% height to the html and body tags work?

Comment: What do you mean by "the image itself in the PDF doesn't fit very well"? Your fiddle actually doesn't look bad if I look at it in Safari on Mac... What's the problem you see and want to have changed?

Comment: What is the point of having an HTML page that contains nothing but a PDF document, as opposite to just putting a PDF document on a server (and linking to it)?